# How to return an element of a list in a list?

Tags: python

So I essentially have a 2 and 1/2 dimensional matrix and I want to return an element from a list within a list.

```
def somefunc(x):
    # What I want to do is return the max element within a matrix based on l[:][1]
    return j

# example
l = [[[1,2,3],4],
    [[5,6,7],8],
    [[9,1,2],3]]

>>>somefunc(l)
[[5,6,7],8]
```

Comment: Isn't this simply `x[1]`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `key` parameter in `max()` function.

```
def somefunc(x):
    return max(x, key=lambda e: e[1])
```